# Windows Server 2016 on Virtual machine, Kiosk mode

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I am trying to set up Kiosk Mode on a Windows Server 2016 set-up on a Hyper-V VM.

I have used Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer to create a Kiosk package but cannot apply it. When I use the Powershell cmdlet `Add-ProvisioningPackage`

I get an error saying:

> 'Add-ProvisioningPackage is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet'

Has anyone else had similar issues?

EDIT: Here is the full error, I tried both the folder path and also the .ppkg
[image]

EDIT2: It appears to not be possible on Windows Server 2016 to utilize provisioning packages.

Comment: Maybe it's [Install-ProvisioningPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/provisioning/install-provisioningpackage?view=win10-ps) now? Or is that something different?

Comment: I've tried that too, i'm wondering if it's just possible on Win 10 and not Server 2016. I thought it would work anyway as from what I've read Server is just a learner version of the OS with Server Manager